# Maintaining a custom modern linux userland ontop of a legacy linux distribution

Tags: linux, scripting, compilation, centos, redhat

Oftentimes I've found myself stuck on old versions linux (usually redhat based). I usually need to have newer compilers, editors, debuggers, and other tools and so I often wind up compiling them myself into some path. Usually its either my home directory for personal stuff, or a shared path on the filesystem for a team.

Compiling the packages is tedious work and can take a lot of time. Uninstalling is even more error prone as you have to keep the source directory around to do a make uninstall. Handling different versions (multiple compilers for example) is also a pain as it usually means compiling into different paths and setting some environment variables to select which one you want.

Are there any good tools out there to make this job easier and less time consuming? Something like RPM where you can pick a path and build/install packages by writing a spec file. Or maybe some system like busybox which handles most of the work for you. Being able to select versions of things (compiler, jvm, etc..) would be even better. It has to be some solution that does not require root.

I know a lot of people must be doing some variant of this. How do you handle this problem?

Comment: Perhaps the easiest one were to use some virtual machine, if applicable.

Comment: Indeed, but in this case we need to use the applications within the host system. We need to build applications which run on the host system and correctly link to their dependent libraries and compilers which we are also building, installing, and sometimes upgrading.

Comment: I don't know, if it helps, but take a look at this [blog](http://alexandernst.blogspot.de/2013/03/cross-compiling-applications-for-arm.html) describing [Scratchbox 2](https://maemo.gitorious.org/scratchbox2).

Comment: Take a look at [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/downloads/manual/manual.html) too. It manages toolchain creation/download and many other things.